# Implementing Page View on an Existing Android Project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'm trying to add my android project some extra layouts but I want to do it with Page View-you know to make layouts slide beetwen each other-. I see a lot of example about that on the internet which I think the best one is [this one.](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) 
But I couldn't figure out how to put this code in my existing project. Can you give me some guidance on the subject. Maybe a tutorial or something.

I have two layouts one of them is activity_main.xml and the other layout is: activity_weekly_weather.xml which is currently empty. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use ViewPager, above url that you wrote on question has show everything about viewpager. You can handle that.

Comment: yeah I understand generic structure, I did a simple example copying that classes on a new project. But I could'nt figure out how to put everything on my existing project. That's the reason I asked for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show you how to implement viewpager in your activity and how to set adapter to viewpager and show fragments in viewpager.

Firstly you should add viewpager to your activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you should set adapter and tablayout to your viewpager:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

TrialAdapter adapter = new TrialAdapter(this, getFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

You need to implement **TrialAdapter** like:

```
public class TrialAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public TrialAdapter(Context context,FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            return new TrialFragment();
        } else{
            return new TrialFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            return "Tab-1";
        } else{
            return "Tab-2";
        }
    }
}
```

You should write your **Fragment** like:

```
public class TrialFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trial, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Finally you should create **fragment_trial.xml** in your layout resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Trial Fragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I recommend you to use `android.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter` so you need to add below lines to your gradle file (app module):

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+' // for FragmentStatePager
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0' // for TabLayout
```

Good luck bro.

Comment: Had to made a few changes to run because of my project structure but it worked! Great effort. Helped a lot, Thanks a lot :)